# Как менять конкретную строку в консоли, а не выводить новую?

Tags: c, консоль

Хочу сделать простой индикатор прогресса, что-то типа "1/10 итераций выполнено". Я знаю и номер текущей итерации и их общее количество, но только не знаю, как менять конкретную строку в консоли, а не выводить новую.

Comment: Выводите строку, завершая ее `\r`.

Comment: @Harry а прям управления кареткой разве нет в си? т.е. не только последнюю строку переписать но и любую иную(или конкретный символ) ?) Плюсом виндовая(или линуксовая, не помню кто из них страдал таким) консоль на \r разве не будет автоматом делать \n?

Comment: \r - это то, что Вам нужно. работать будет как нужно. Единственное, что добивайте пробелами справа, иначе будет выглядеть некрасиво. Переводить не будет, это не в этом месте оно конвертирует.

Comment: Спасибо, всё хорошо работает, но есть одна проблема. Можно ли как-то скрыть курсор? Он просто очень раздражающе бегает

Comment: тут сложнее. но можно. Но может все такие подключить какой-нибуть ncurses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать что-то вроде этого если прям по-простому и без заморочек

```
#if defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64)
#include <windows.h>
    #define HIDECUR() SetConsoleCursorInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &(CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO){.dwSize = 100, .bVisible = FALSE});
    #define SETPOS(x,y)  SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), (COORD){.X = x, .Y = y})
#else
    #define HIDECUR() printf("\x1b[?25l") 
    #define SETPOS(x,y) printf("\x1b[%d;%dH", y, x)
#endif
```

Comment: в стандартной виндовой консоли esc последовательности тоже работают, может и эта работает.

Comment: А разве не надо сначала включить такое поведение?

Comment: нет. в стандартном cmd - у меня работает много esc последовательностей, как минимум цвета и перемещения курсора. А вот в Windows Terminal Preview - как то плохо-плохо.

Comment: @KoVadim Что-то давно я не встречал в Windows работающего ANSI... Это в каких Windows у вас работает?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences
Первый пример у меня работает! Но если убрать установку режима virtual terminal sequences то не робит! (Windows 10 Pro 20H2)

Comment: @Harry - на 10 (21H2 OS build 19044.1706). как минимум "\033[38;5;" для цвета и "\033[2J" для очистки экрана работает в cmd.exe

Comment: @KoVadim См. https://ibb.co/dLCmpF4...

Comment: какие то чудеса происходят. Запускаю с под студии - работает как нужно ( в примере на скрине (НА СКРИНЕ!!!, а не текстом) есть ошибка, запускаю с под cmd - не хочет. чудеса. работало же. я просто показывал всем это. либо обновление какое-то сломало, либо я не учел какой то фактор.